# How to set a Background Image for a Kendo DataViz Chart

Tags: charts, kendo-ui, kendo-dataviz

How can I set the background image for a Kendoui chart?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically you need to apply that background style to the element from which you initialize the chart.

e.g.

```
<div id="chart" style="background: center no-repeat url('someImage.png');"></div>
```

Like in this online [demo](http://demos.kendoui.com/dataviz/line-charts/index.html).

Comment: Tried the same thing for Kendo Stockchart but couldn't make it work as in this  
[Example](http://jsbin.com/izuyoz/6/). 
Can you please check what might be the problem?